# Moving Xml data To SQL Table via SSIS /SCRIPT

Tags: sql, xml, ssis

Now i know this isn't new, and really, I've done plenty of study on the site looking for a similar problem. I have an xml data  like this:

```
<CanvasResult>
<TotalPages>1</TotalPages>
<CurrentPage>1</CurrentPage>
<Submissions>
<Submission Id="2257280">
<Form Id="414131">
<Name>NATIONAL CENSUS MOBILE PORTAL</Name>
<Status>published</Status>
<Version>1</Version>
</Form>
<Date>2013.05.26 10:38:16</Date>
<DeviceDate>2013.05.26 11:43:48</DeviceDate>
<UserName>talk2sexydainty1@yahoo.com</UserName>
<FirstName>Kalifat</FirstName>
<LastName>Census</LastName>
<ResponseID>2A5B1951-1369565028972</ResponseID>
<Sections>
<Section>
<Name>Census Data Capture Portal</Name>
<Screens>
<Screen>
<Name>Census Data Capture Portal</Name>
<Responses>
<Response>
<Label>FirstName:</Label>
<Value>ajape</Value>
<Type>Text Box</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>LastName:</Label>
<Value>quadri</Value>
<Type>Text Box</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>ID Number:</Label>
<Value>58rs5</Value>
<Type>Text Box</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Nationality:</Label>
<Value>Nigerian</Value>
<Type>Text Box</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Marital Status:</Label>
<Value>Married</Value>
<Type>Value List</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Date Of Birth:</Label>
<Value>08/26/2000</Value>
<Type>Date</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Gender:</Label>
<Value>Male</Value>
<Type>Value List</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Residential Address:</Label>
<Value>No godwon omonua</Value>
<Type>Multi-Line Text</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Phone No:</Label>
<Value>08134463976</Value>
<Type>Text Box</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Disability</Label>
<Value>NO</Value>
<Type>Value List</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Photo Capture</Label>
<Value>130268022</Value>
<Type>Image Capture</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Education:</Label>
<Value>Degree</Value>
<Type>Value List</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Ex Convict:</Label>
<Value>NO</Value>
<Type>Value List</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Career:</Label>
<Value>eCommerce</Value>
<Type>Value List</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Work Experience:</Label>
<Value>Average</Value>
<Type>Value List</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Current Employer:</Label>
<Value>primeplastichem nig ltd</Value>
<Type>Text Box</Type>
</Response>
</Responses>
</Screen>
</Screens>
</Section>
</Sections>
</Submission>
<Submission Id="2263781">
<Form Id="414131">
<Name>NATIONAL CENSUS MOBILE PORTAL</Name>
<Status>published</Status>
<Version>1</Version>
</Form>
<Date>2013.05.28 12:12:51</Date>
<DeviceDate>2013.05.28 12:05:01</DeviceDate>
<UserName>talk2sexydainty1@yahoo.com</UserName>
<FirstName>Kalifat</FirstName>
<LastName>Census</LastName>
<ResponseID>2A5B1951-1369739101634</ResponseID>
<Sections>
<Section>
<Name>Census Data Capture Portal</Name>
<Screens>
<Screen>
<Name>Census Data Capture Portal</Name>
<Responses>
<Response>
<Label>FirstName:</Label>
<Value>micheal</Value>
<Type>Text Box</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>LastName:</Label>
<Value>eniolade</Value>
<Type>Text Box</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>ID Number:</Label>
<Value>1256</Value>
<Type>Text Box</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Nationality:</Label>
<Value>Nigerian</Value>
<Type>Text Box</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Marital Status:</Label>
<Value>Single</Value>
<Type>Value List</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Date Of Birth:</Label>
<Value>01/28/1986</Value>
<Type>Date</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Gender:</Label>
<Value>Male</Value>
<Type>Value List</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Residential Address:</Label>
<Value>Orisunbare</Value>
<Type>Multi-Line Text</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Phone No:</Label>
<Value>08039255000</Value>
<Type>Text Box</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Disability</Label>
<Value>NO</Value>
<Type>Value List</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Photo Capture</Label>
<Value>130574405</Value>
<Type>Image Capture</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Education:</Label>
<Value>Degree</Value>
<Type>Value List</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Ex Convict:</Label>
<Value>NO</Value>
<Type>Value List</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Career:</Label>
<Value>Information Technology</Value>
<Type>Value List</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Work Experience:</Label>
<Value>Expert</Value>
<Type>Value List</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Current Employer:</Label>
<Value>micheal</Value>
<Type>Text Box</Type>
</Response>
</Responses>
</Screen>
</Screens>
</Section>
</Sections>
</Submission>
<Submission Id="2288255">
<Form Id="414131">
<Name>NATIONAL CENSUS MOBILE PORTAL</Name>
<Status>published</Status>
<Version>1</Version>
</Form>
<Date>2013.05.31 13:53:51</Date>
<DeviceDate>2013.05.31 13:37:16</DeviceDate>
<UserName>ochonogorf@gmail.com</UserName>
<FirstName>Felix</FirstName>
<LastName>Okechukwu</LastName>
<ResponseID>923297e829f566c6-1370007436433</ResponseID>
<Sections>
<Section>
<Name>Census Data Capture Portal</Name>
<Screens>
<Screen>
<Name>Census Data Capture Portal</Name>
<Responses>
<Response>
<Label>FirstName:</Label>
<Value>Felix</Value>
<Type>Text Box</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>LastName:</Label>
<Value>Blaze</Value>
<Type>Text Box</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>ID Number:</Label>
<Value>00996325</Value>
<Type>Text Box</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Nationality:</Label>
<Value>Nigerian</Value>
<Type>Text Box</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Marital Status:</Label>
<Value>Married</Value>
<Type>Value List</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Date Of Birth:</Label>
<Value>05/31/1984</Value>
<Type>Date</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Gender:</Label>
<Value>Male</Value>
<Type>Value List</Type>
</Response>
<Response>
<Label>Residential Address:</Label>
<Value>Lagos</Value>
<Type>Multi-Line Text</Type>
</Response>
</Responses>
</Screen>
</Screens>
</Section>
</Sections>
</Submission>
</Submissions>
</CanvasResult>
```

Sorry, I know its long and boring! The important tags is the responses-Label Values. I've created a sql table with Similar fields(first name, Lastname, Id number etc). I don't know how best to get the data. I tried XML Source in SSIS, but it didn't seem to generate the XSD quite right, probably cos of the structure of the xml. I'm not very strong yet, though I love ssis.. im guessing the wizard wont work.. I also think it probably needs abit of scripting, as the xml data could be much more, or less. I use C# and sql 2012. Pls could anyone put me tru on how to move the xml records to database efficiently? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the structure of your xml using an xslt transformation using an xml task in ssis.
Matt Masson wrote a comprehensive blog post on the subject: [xml-source-making-things-easier-with-xslt](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2007/12/15/xml-source-making-things-easier-with-xslt.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If the XML Source is inflexible have you thought about coding your own solution in a script component? You could make use of the  [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class to deserialize this and add it to your data flow. A example of how you would deserialize it can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsh84875%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Once you deserialize the XML, you can then send that data to an [output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9659d2d2-5d73-4470-9768-e07b77142fc9) on your component.